# Make Textview height expand to match the bigger Textview height size in same horizontal Lane

Tags: xml, android-layout

I want to make the other textviews in horizontal lane same size with the bigger textview ( i don't know the size of it, at app start ).
I'm using barrier on top & ender every textview lane.
posted code of only one line of textetviews.

[Image attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwGzv.jpg)

Using ConstraintLayout

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        app:barrierDirection="bottom"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="tv_BM_item_qnt,tv_item_name,img_item_icon,tv_BM_item_price"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="80dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_BW_sell_price"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FF6E40"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/barrier2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tv_LH_sell_price"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/barrier1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_LH_sell_price"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#91FB17"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/barrier2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tv_ML_sell_price"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tv_BW_sell_price"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/barrier1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_ML_sell_price"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#17ABFB"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/barrier2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tv_TF_sell_price"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tv_LH_sell_price"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/barrier1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_TF_sell_price"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FB17E4"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/barrier2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tv_FS_sell_price"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tv_ML_sell_price"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/barrier1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_FS_sell_price"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/barrier2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tv_CL_sell_price"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tv_TF_sell_price"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/barrier1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_CL_sell_price"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FB1717"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/barrier2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tv_FS_sell_price"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/barrier1" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="bottom"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="tv_LH_sell_price,tv_ML_sell_price,tv_FS_sell_price,tv_BW_sell_price,tv_TF_sell_price,tv_CL_sell_price"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="730dp" />
```

why i need to type more text if my question is simple...ohh i need to type more text how levely...anyway thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using TableLayout.
Exemple:

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent">

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FF6E40"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#91FB17"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#17ABFB"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FB17E4"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:text="Long Text Exemple: Loooooooong" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FB1717"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:text="TextView" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FF6E40"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#91FB17"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#17ABFB"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FB17E4"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FF0000"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:text="TextView" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```